# add a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have problems to add a specific column "happiness_average" form variable pd_dictionnary of type "pandas" to another variable `pd_dictionnary_treat`  of type "pandas"

I tried to tape `pd_dictionnary_treat.append(pd_dictionnary["happiness_average"]`) in my code below:

```
import pandas as pd

pd_dictionnary=pd.read_csv("/Users/stefanhanssen/Dropbox/hse/word_list/131278/Data_Set_S1.txt",sep="\t")

pd_dictionnary_treat=pd_dictionnary["word"]


pd_dictionnary_treat.append(pd_dictionnary["happiness_average"])

print(pd_dictionnary_treat)
```

My expected result is to have in my variable `pd_dictionnary_treat` two columns :

First one : `pd_dictionnary["word"]`
second one : `pd_dictionnary["happiness_average"]`

The actual result is one column in the variable `pd_dictionnary_treat` that is `pd_dictionnary["word"]`

Here is my Data_Set_S1.txt file
[Data_Set_S1.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6n3M.png)

Comment: `pd_dictionnary_treat= pd_dictionnary[["word", "happiness_average"]]`? Other than that, I don't follow the question. It seems that `"happiness_average"` is already in the df, otherwise I don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: please provide your input csv file and expected output example. @Stefan Hanssen

Comment: Do you want to add new rows onto the bottom of the dataframe? [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) does exactly that. I think something like what @roganjosh suggest is more what you are after.

Comment: @roganjosh I try your code but it does not work, I try to add the column "happiness_average" from the variable pd_dictionnary to the variable pd_dictionnary_treat

Comment: @Nisheet Patel  I just add it in the description

Comment: Yes, but where is it coming from if it's not already _in_ `pd_dictionnary`? Without example input and expected output, we simply can't answer this.

Comment: @Gavin I don't want to add row but an additional column to the variable pd_dictionnary_treat extracted from the variable pd_dictionnary

Comment: @roganjosh Yes it is already in pd_dictionnary, I just want to extract the column "happiness_average" to add it to the variable pd_dictionnary_treat

Comment: What do you get from `print(pd_dictionnary.columns)`?

Comment: @roganjosh I get "Index(['word', 'happiness_rank', 'happiness_average',
       'happiness_standard_deviation', 'twitter_rank', 'google_rank',
       'nyt_rank', 'lyrics_rank'],
      dtype='object')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you use `append` function?
You can directly add at the time of assigning `word` column to `pd_dictionnary_treat`.
I think this will help you:

```
import pandas as pd
pd_dictionnary=pd.read_csv("/Users/stefanhanssen/Dropbox/hse/word_list/131278/Data_Set_S1.txt",sep="\t")
pd_dictionnary_treat= pd_dictionnary[["word","happiness_average"]]
print(pd_dictionnary_treat)
```